# How to play pause audio file in python?

Tags: python, vlc, audio-player

I am trying to create a media player with Python that will play mp3 files one after the other and allow me to play and pause the music at any time (similar to spotify).

I have used the vlc library and pygame music function to play the files, but my problem comes when the song has finished and I want it to play the next file. I have manged to do this but not with a play and pause functionality.

My rough code:

```py
import pygame
import time

#plays first mp3 file
file = '4c68Z9wLdHc36y3CNjwQKM.ogg'
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

#play and pause funtionnality

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    timer = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
    time.sleep(1)
    control = input()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
    if control == "pause":
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    elif control == "play" :
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    elif control == "time":
        timer = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
        timer = timer/1000
        print (str(timer))
    elif int(timer) > 10:
        print ("True")
        pygame.mixer.music.stop() 
        break
    else:
        pass

 #next mp3 file   

file = '3qiyyUfYe7CRYLucrPmulD.ogg' 
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

When I run this my hope is that it will play the first file and allow me to play and pause, but it stops when a song ends and not play the next one, as it gets stuck waiting for an input.

I want it to play the first file, allowing me to pause and resume it at any time, and then when the song has finished, it automatically plays the next file.

Thanks in advance.

To narrow it down I would like to know how to create a while that has a user input that will always check for a condition and not just at the start of the while loop.

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you can narrow down your question to the specific portion of your issue and reduce the code to a smaller bit, it will be easier for SO members to help.

Comment: What do you mean : `Not just at the start of the while loop` ?

Comment: If you use a while loop with a condition it will check if the condition is met at the start, then continue and in this case get stuck at the "input()" waiting for an input. But when waiting the original condition might become false and it will only recheck the condition when the while tries to run again which it can't as it is stuck at the "input()". So what I am asking is there a way for it to check for the original condition whilst waiting for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you tagged this question `vlc` if you are using `pygame` as arguably `vlc.py` has this functionallity pretty much built in.
However, all you need to do is use a double `while` statement.
The first controls the file to be played and the second performs your play/pause control. e.g.

```
import pygame
import time

files = ['./vp1.mp3','./vp.mp3']
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
stepper = 0
#file loading
while stepper < len(files):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(files[stepper])
    print("Playing:",files[stepper])
    stepper += 1
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
#play and pause
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        timer = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
        time.sleep(1)
        control = input()
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
        if control == "pause":
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        elif control == "play" :
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        elif control == "time":
            timer = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
            timer = timer/1000
            print (str(timer))
        elif int(timer) > 10:
            print ("True")
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            break
        else:
            continue
```